# How to use Google Play Store for testing

Tags: android, google-play

I am new to the Google play store. I was getting frustrated with play store. I have uploaded to the Production and it takes several hours to publish on the store.I do not know how to use alpha and beta properly,because production takes lot of time to publish the app. There are many restrictions regarding
versions and key store files. Can any body please suggest how to deal with it?

I have the following doubts regarding play store.

- Shall we upload the same app to the alpha as well as production with same version and pkg name?
- Shall alpha takes less time compare to production?
- What is the way to reduce the time to publish on play store?
- If it takes several hours, I think there is no strong reason to use Google Play store?
- How the people publishing the number of apps on play store, if it takes longer time?

Thanks in advance for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using HockeyApp as a hub to store our development apps in order to our testers keep track of it. It is very easy to integrate within your app. It also has a very quickly publishing process and it provides a very useful feature so tester can report bugs directly from the app.

Take a look on it.

http://hockeyapp.net

Comment: I have registered with hockeyapp.net, may i know how to access my uploaded app.

Comment: To access your app you do through the HockeyApp application (Play Store). Then you have access to all the app you have released or invited.

Comment: can you please tell me exact app name for searching in the play store, because i am getting hockey game apps

Comment: Sorry @M.S Naidu. I thought you can get in PlayStore, but you can't. You have to download the app directly from the website: http://hockeyapp.net/apps/

Comment: I downloaded the desktop app but it is asking to install .net framework.

Comment: well, I don't use desktop app, I usually use the mobile device version.

Comment: Thank you so much @nep0x.I have got it actullay. but can we ensure that the same app will work on play store..

Comment: You are welcome. I do not see any reason for it didn't work in playstore...

Comment: Yes you are right, but how can we ensure that will it work on play store. because we are uploading signed apk in play store where as normal in hockey app.